# Angular 4 - Inserting a new API response into an API response

Tags: javascript, angular, api, typescript, asynchronous

I have a simple async .NET API setup and I'm trying to gather my data in my TypeScript component. I am populating customerTransactions and trying to insert transactionDetails onto it.

My code is below:

```
this.apiService.GetCustomerTransactions(this.customerNumber, startDate, endDate).subscribe(
    customerTransactions => {
        this.customerTransactions = customerTransactions;
        this.orderCount = this.customerTransactions.length;

        for (var i = 0; i < this.customerTransactions.length; i++) {
           this.apiService.GetCustomerTransactionDetails(this.customerNumber, this.customerTransactions[i].storeNumber, this.customerTransactions[i].transactionNumber).subscribe(
               customerTransactionDetails => {
                   this.customerTransactions[i].transactionDetails = customerTransactionDetails;
                   //console.log(customerTransactionDetails);
               }
           );
        }
        //console.log(this.customerTransactions);
    }
);
```

The part that's confusing to me is why the commented out console.log is returning the expected response, but when I try to add it to my existing array, I'm having issues and getting a "ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'transactionDetails' of undefined" message in the console for each row.

Your help is appreciated!

Comment: You should try logging `customerTransactions` when you receive it. The array might contain an `undefined` element.

Comment: I tried logging customerTransactions after 'this.orderCount' and the output is perfect. I have a feeling that I need to make some sort of promise when I'm getting the data -- but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: customerTransactions does have a `transactionDetails` field, correct?

Comment: You can't know in what order you'll receive responses from your API. For instance, it's not sure `GetCustomerTransactionDetails` call for `i = 0` will receive its response before the call for `i = 1`. You should make an array of calls to `GetCustomerTransactionDetails` for the different values of `i` and then use `Observable.forkJoin([...])` to receive the responses in the right order.

Comment: I think you're right. The responses are coming back in a different order each time.